# CakePhp - Associated Data not Saving (but main model data does save)

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

So, I have a form in CakePhp using it's Formhelper. There are two associated models in this form: Booking & Guest. The database tables seem to be setup correctly since the page populates the values accurately enough through the associations in the model.

When saving my form data, the Booking information saves but not the Guest information. I've simplified the code in the snippets below. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

**Model**

```
class Booking extends AppModel {
public $name = "Booking";

/*Associations Section*/
public $belongsTo = array('Property','Bookingsource');
public $hasMany = array('Payment','Occupant','Bookingfee');
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Addon',
    'Guest' => array(
        'unique' => FALSE
    )
);
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function edit($id) {
    if ($this -> request -> is('post')) {
        if ($this -> Booking -> saveAll($this -> request -> data)) {
            $this -> Session -> setFlash('Booking Edited Successully!', "goodflash");
        } else {
            $this -> Session -> setFlash('Oops Something went wrong!', "badflash");
        }
    } else {
        $this->data = $this -> Booking -> findById($id);
        $this -> set('bookingid', $id);
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create("Booking", array('type' => 'post'));
echo $this -> Form -> hidden('Booking.id');
echo $this -> Form -> input('Booking.property_id');
echo $this -> Form -> input('Booking.checkin');
echo $this -> Form -> input('Booking.checkout');
echo $this -> Form -> input('Guest.0.firstname');
echo $this -> Form -> end("Submit");
?>
```

When looking at the SQL that's being processed, I don't see anything to suggest an attempt to edit the Guest table attached to my model.

```
5   UPDATE `cake_bookingsystem`.`bookings` SET `id` = '10000', `property_id` = '01', `checkin` = '2012-11-10', `checkout` = '2012-12-13' WHERE `cake_bookingsystem`.`bookings`.`id` = '10000'       0   0   8
6   COMMIT      0   0   8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the id field of the guest record also in your view:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create("Booking", array('type' => 'post'));
echo $this -> Form -> hidden('Booking.id');
echo $this -> Form -> input('Booking.property_id');
echo $this -> Form -> input('Booking.checkin');
echo $this -> Form -> input('Booking.checkout');
echo $this -> Form -> input('Guest.0.id');
echo $this -> Form -> input('Guest.0.firstname');
echo $this -> Form -> end("Submit");
```

?>

Comment: Tried adding the ID field. Still no luck. Again, any changes to the main booking information commits but any change to the guest does nothing. Frustrating!!

Comment: is any data being written at all to the guest table while editing or adding?

Comment: Not when saving via this form. Creating a form based directly on the Guest model saves and updates correctly but the goal here is to do this within the booking form as above. Also, as mentioned, the SQL code doesn't suggest that cake is even attempting to save anything related to the guest model.