# UPDATE columns in one-to-many related tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp

Suppose you have a `table A` related to another `table B` by a `one-to-many` (`hasMany`) relation. `Table B` can have other `hasMany` relations and so on.

For instance, I am trying to do it in cakePhp, but I think it is a general SQL problem.
Suppose that in every table there is a column, `user_id`.

There is a way to update all the columns `user_id` in all related `table` with one `SQL construct`? Or rather, which is the fastest way to do it? Now, I could not find a solution but doing it by iteration, and, obviously this is quite time-consuming and server-overloading.

Comment: that's one of the reasons you use a surrogate key....

Comment: Can you explain what a surrogate key is?

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14064522/cakephp-associated-data-not-saving-but-main-model-data-does-save might be helpful to you

Comment: Actually, I am trying to make a method which does what I would, i.e. whithout form data...

Comment: "Can you explain what a surrogate key is?" - have you considered a search engine?

Comment: Yes I found it but I do not understand how to use it in my particular problem...

Comment: Update all the `user_id`'s to what?

Comment: To a new value... Imagine that user_id is the owner of the record and the related ones

Comment: You need to do it with one query for each type of thing (table) you want to transfer.

Comment: @Vate: and that is my current solution (very expensive!)

Comment: Why is it very expensive? How many/big tables do you need to update?

Comment: You can remove some overhead by creating a stored proc to do the updates, but I don't think you will be able to do better without changing the schema.